# What's the difference between 'killall' and 'pkill'?

Tags: command-line, process

After using just plain `kill <some_pid>` on Unix systems for many years, I learned `pkill` from a younger Linux-savvy <strike>co-worker</strike> colleague<sup>1</sup>.

I soon accepted the Linux-way,`pgrep`-ing and `pkill`-ing through many days and nights, through slow-downs and race conditions.   This was all well and good.

But now I see nothing but `killall`.  How-to's seem to only mention `killall`, and I'm not sure if this is some kind of parallel development, or if `killall` is a successor to `pkill`, or something else.

It seems to function as a more targeted `pkill`, but I'm sure I'm missing something.

Can an Ubuntu/Debian-savvy<sup>2</sup> person explain when (or why) `killall` should be used, especially if it should be used in preference to `pkill` (when `pkill` often seems easier, because I can be sloppier with name matching, at least by default).

When speaking of `killall`, I'm not thinking of the command that on some Unix systems (Solaris, AIX, ?) would kill all user processes.   Here's a description of that version, from [a manpage for IBM's AIX](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds3/killall.htm):

> The killall command cancels all
>   processes that you started, except
>   those producing the killall process.
>   This command provides a convenient
>   means of canceling all processes
>   created by the shell that you control.
>   When started by a root user, the
>   killall command cancels all
>   cancellable processes except those
>   processes that started it. If several
>   Signals are specified, only the last
>   one is effective.

<sup>1</sup> 'colleague' is free upgrade from 'co-worker', so might as well.
<sup>2</sup> Originally I thought this was a Linux or Debian thing, but some sources are saying that the Linux `killall` is derived from BSD-flavored Unix.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I think you see killall in how-to's because by default it requires the precise process name, whereas pkill does basic pattern matching. **Thus, killall is safer for users to blindly copy and paste.**

Pkill and killall both have distinguishing options. Killall has a flag to match by process age, pkill has a flag to only kill processes on a given tty. Etcetera ad nauseum. **Neither is better**, they just have different specialties.

I see from their man pages that killall comes from the [psmisc package](http://psmisc.sourceforge.net/), which has several process managing utilities, but notably doesn't contain `ps`. It's the [procps package](http://procps.sourceforge.net/) that has ps, top, kill, and pkill (among others). I'd wager procps didn't originally have pkill, so psmisc scratched an itch and came up with killall.

The [pkill/pgrep man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) says they were introduced in Solaris 7. As you mention, *jgbelacqua*, Solaris's killall was not the utility psmisc provides, thus Solaris probably only had the procps package. Someone wanted a pattern matching process tool, thus pkill and pgrep. Whether it was developed by the procps dev or added in afterwards, I don't know. Regardless, it made it in and became part of *nixes everywhere.

**More sources:**

- http://www.freebsdsoftware.org/sysutils/linux-procps.html
- http://www.freebsdsoftware.org/sysutils/psmisc.html
- http://procps.sourceforge.net/faq.html
- [OpenSolaris (now Illumos) source code for ps, at launch in 2005](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/sys/procfs.h?r=7c478bd95313f5f23a4c958a745db2134aa03244)

Comment: Hmm -- there was a `killall` on (old?) Solaris systems, but it behaved differently.  It killed everything.

Comment: `killall` kills all the process with the specified name.

Comment: @manish -- er, there was a different killall on SysV systems.

Comment: @djeikyb  The thought about killall being safer sounds right, or at least that could account for a lot of its popularity.

Comment: @jgbelacqua: It is easier to use `killall` since the process guess is easy to guess whereas finding pid itself takes one extra step.

Comment: @Manish: pkill (no kill) doesn't need the pid number, nor the process name. It does patter match on the process name.

Comment: `killall is safer for users to blindly copy and paste`, except if you're on a machine where killall does really kill all. It's unfortunate that the two different utilities come to have the same name.

Comment: @LieRyan what gnu/linux provides a `killall` that behaves like solaris's? As well documented in both the question and answer, we're not talking about *that* `killall`.

Answer (score 7):

Please be careful with "killall".  On some systems (I forget which), killall kills *all* processes.  It will silently ignore arguments and bring your system to a complete halt.

Comment: This is not true.  killall without any arguments will do nothing, and killall will not ignore the arguments.  `kill -9 -1` might kill your system, and `killall -9 -1` might as well.  But not just `killall [program]`

Comment: It's true on SysV systems, as now mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 5):

if you activate /etc/bash_completion, after `killall <part_of_process_name>` and hit tab - auto completes the process name from the list of running processes

Comment: The same auto-completion will be done with pgrep/pkill.  Something I commonly do is `pkill plug<tab>` to kill the flash plugin for firefox when I know that I don't have anything I want to use for a while but still want to actively use firefox.  This is a function of the shell, not a difference between killall and pgrep/pkill.

Comment: I didn't say is a difference - just a nice feature to avoid searching for PIDs, process names and etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the options on both programs, you'll see that they both do about the same thing, but in different ways.

pkill will perform matching on various attributes of a process (CMD, PID, PPID, UID...) and will send the given signal to each process that matches. (For CMD, a regular expression is used, for others it is a string). pkill is not interactive, but better for batch programs.

killall will perform matching on the process name (comm) or user (user), not on the whole command string. The argument is used as a simple string and must be match the entire 'comm' value (there is also a --regexp option to change this).  killall has --interactive and --younger-than options, which pkill does not have.

There is also a killall5 is from SysV days and was ported to other UNIX variants (supposedly under the Ubuntu package 'sysutils').  This behaves differently in the old fashion manner.  This was often used internally to the init scripts to shutdown or change to single-user mode.

Comment: No, neither `pkill` nor `killall` should be used in scripts, only interactively, and with caution.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the other answers, another difference making it a bit more idiot proof is that `killall` will tell you

> no process found

if that process doesn't exist, while `pkill` won't.