# How do I kill processes in Ubuntu?

Tags: process, users, kill

How do I kill all processes running by my own non-root account?

I have some spinning smbd  processes that I caused from my windows machine and so I telnetted into the linux server and I want to kill those spinning processes.   I don't have authority to restart services or reboot the machine.

Answer (score 257, accepted):

To kill all the processes that you have the permission to kill, simply run the command

`kill -15 -1` or `kill -9 -1` depending on the desired behavior (use `man kill` for details)

To kill a specific process, say, firefox, simply run

`pkill firefox` or `killall firefox` depending on the behavior you want: [What's the difference between 'killall' and 'pkill'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27501/whats-the-difference-between-killall-and-pkill)

If you want to see what processes are running use the command

```
ps -ef
```

If you want to look up all processes by user bob, this might help

```
pgrep -l -u bob
```

or

```
ps -ef | grep bob
```

Comment: I'd start with `kill -15 -1`, and only move on to `kill -9 -1` if there are stubborn processes and **I know what I'm doing**. Randomly killing processes that may be in the middle of a database transaction is not something one should do as casually as you suggest.

Comment: Also, Firefox's process is named `firefox-bin`.

Comment: No, you can try running `killall firefox` and `killall firefox-bin` and see what works. I agree with your first comment.

Comment: Thanks @ste_kwr, worked with your instructions, after struggling for two days...

Comment: The advantage to not needing PIDs is in cron jobs.  Using names works out cleanly.

Comment: `top` is a nice command I like to use to see what processes are running and a little more information on how much resources they are using etc.

Comment: What is -15 and what is -1?

Answer (score 115):

Use `sudo kill <pid>` or `sudo killall <process-name>`

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to this question, you are using sudo -- the OP has not such privileges, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: The OP doesn't have privileges, please edit your answer or it may be deleted or converted into a comment as "not an answer".

Comment: If he doesn't have privileges he just have to do kill <pid> or killall <process-name> I just used it in my non root account, I wouldn't be able to do it if it wasn't for this Answer.

Answer (score 46):

You can use

```
ps -ax | grep application name
```

If your searching for firefox type in terminal like `ps -ax | grep firefox`, it shows the process id of corresponding application. You can stop that application by `kill` command if process id=1317,

```
kill -9 1317
```

Answer (score 25):

Let's try something more:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

The `top` command is the traditional way to view your system’s resource usage and see the processes that are taking up the most system resources. Top displays a list of processes, with the ones using the most CPU at the top.

`htop` displays the same information with an easier-to-understand layout. It also lets you select processes with the arrow keys and perform actions, such as killing them or changing their priority, with the <kbd>F</kbd> keys.

Answer (score 17):

I would use `xkill`. Enter `xkill` in a terminal and click in the window, or enter `xkill` and the process ID and it will be terminated.

Found out more about `xkill` on [x.org.](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xkill.1.xhtml)

Comment: Use it second in frequency after pkill nd love it. +1

Comment: xkill doesnt work in this case...

Comment: @PythoNic in what case is that?

Comment: He wants to kill a non-window process which is also not related to the X server as it seems for me... (Anyway a good tool.)

Comment: This blocked my mouse cursor and I had to do `sudo killall xkill`!

Answer (score 11):

I'd break your problem into 2 parts:

1) How do I find the processes started by me? Run this:

```
ps -u `whoami`
```

The `whoami` is just in case you don't know the name of the account you are using, otherwise just type the name of the account without the back quotes.

This will list all processes that can be deleted by your account.

2) The `ps` command will list the process number, the TTY, Time, and CMD. The process ID is the first column. Use that number to kill the process. Be careful while killing the process. You might break something if you kill the wrong process.
To kill a process you will use the `kill` command, which sends a SIGNAL to the process. The signal indicates what the process *should* do. For example, sending a `-1` to the process will ask it to reload the configuration file; sending a `-2` is equivalent to pressing the Control+C on that process; `-9` will cause the kernel to abandon the process, without communicating it to the process.

Supposing that  ps -u `whoami` returned something like

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4333 pts/1    00:00:00 fish
 4335 ?        00:00:00 fishd
 4816 ?        00:00:00 intellij
 4868 ?        00:50:42 java
 4939 ?        00:00:19 fsnotifier64
 7667 ?        02:49:08 firefox
 7698 ?        00:00:00 unity-webapps-s
```

And you wanted to kill the `firefox` process by its process id, then you'd do:

```
kill -1 7667
```

Then you'd re-run the same `ps` command and check if the process was still running. If it is still running, then do a

```
kill -2 7667
```

working your way up to `-9`.

To kill all processes started by your account, enter `kill <level> -1`. Same as before: work your way up to `-9`.

If you know the name of the process you can simply go `killall <processname>`, where the  is what you are trying to kill. For example: `killall fish` (fish, in this sense, is the Friendly Interactive SHell).

Documentation for `killall` can be found here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/killall.1.html

Answer (score 9):

To try to kill all processes owned by a user `username`, run:

```
pkill -U username
```

Answer (score 4):

With this application you can view program listings

install htop

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

for see process and kill process 
You can install it and simply delete

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a little script I wrote to kill (in my case) Skype:

```
kill -s 9 `ps aux | grep skype | head -n 1 | cut -f4 -d" "`
```

But I found that as much as that worked then, it didn't work the next day because the pid was a different length and there for the amount of spaces was different

Then I came across this site and tried

```
pgrep -l -u justin
```

which conveniently outputs processes in the format

```
[pid] [name]
```

So I adjusted my code in the script to this:

```
kill -s 9 `pgrep -l -u justin | grep skype | cut -f1 -d" "`
```

What this does is pipes all of the processes `justin` is running (that can be changed to any user name) to `grep` which looks for `skype` (this can be changed to your process) and then pipes that line to `cut` which then reads only the PID and finally uses that PID in the `kill` command to kill it.

Comment: You could have dropped the `-l`, and ran `pgrep -u justin skype`, and to kill: `pkill -u justin skype` (or `pkill -KILL -u justin skype` to send SIGKILL).

Comment: This is definitely the Unix Way.  Well done both of you.  I will use this one.

Answer (score 2):

...All processes in Linux respond to signals. Signals are an os-level way of telling programs to terminate or modify their behavior.

How To Send Processes Signals by PID

The most common way of passing signals to a program is with the kill command.

As you might expect, the default functionality of this utility is to attempt to kill a process:

```
kill PID_of_target_process
```

This sends the TERM signal to the process. The TERM signal tells the process to please terminate. This allows the program to perform clean-up operations and exit smoothly.

If the program is misbehaving and does not exit when given the TERM signal, we can escalate the signal by passing the KILL signal:

```
kill -KILL PID_of_target_process
```

This is a special signal that is not sent to the program.

Instead, it is given to the operating system kernel, which shuts down the process. This is used to bypass programs that ignore the signals sent to them...

Answer (score 0):

I used following procedure to kill a process in Ubuntu ::

Step 1 : Get the pid of the process by using grep or you can use -C also ::

```
ps aux | -C 'filename'
```

or

```
ps -ef | -C 'filename'
```

or

```
ps aux | grep 'filename'
```

or

```
ps -ef | grep 'filename'
```

Step 2 : Note the pid number .

Step 3 : Use 'kill' command alongwith the pid number as :

```
kill pidnumber
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> can be set to give you access to the task manager, from where it's easy to kill processes with a couple clicks, and for me, less requirement for remembering commands that could be damaging if done wrong:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/use-ctrl-alt-del-task-manager-ubuntu/

https://www.itsmarttricks.com/a-guide-to-kill-pkill-and-killall-commands-to-stop-the-process-in-linux-kill-process-linux/