# Forcefullly kill a process in Ubuntu

Tags: kill, task-management

How can I forcefully stop a process in ubuntu, like we can do from task manager in ubuntu. look its not the same question as you indicate here. I want a feature in ubuntu 15 which is just same as task manager in windows. i.e. not just kill a process but also do rest of the jobs of the task manager.

Comment: another very similar Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/104903/how-do-i-kill-processes-in-ubuntu

Comment: And what do you think [Paranoid Panda's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/641646/158442) gives?

Answer (score 4):

If you mean in terminal you would need to run this command.

- `kill -9` kills processes instantly

  ```
  kill -9 <process id>
  ```
- `pkill` will allow you to use the process name

  ```
  pkill -9 <processname>
  ```
- or if you have multiple processes running like say chrome you would do something like this

  ```
  sudo killall -9 <process name>
  ```

Hope this helps answer your question

Comment: Anyway, it's always better to try to kill the process with a `-TERM` (-15) signal before, and using `KILL` (-9) only if the former don't work. That will give the process a chance to clean up before exiting.

Comment: ya true i just figured he was wanting it extremely forceful but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Launch the System Monitor by searching for it in the Unity dashboard:

[image: Unity search System Monitor results]

Then make sure that you are in the `Processes` tab:

[image: Processes tab selected]

Right-click on the process you wish to kill and select `Kill` from the right-click menu:

[image: Kill Process menu]

Then click `Kill` on the confirmation dialog that pops up:

[image: Confirm Kill process Dialog]

Although it might be more advisable to select `End` from the right-click pull-down menu, but it really depends on how unresponsive the process is.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type `xkill`

   A cross appears on screen. click it on the application you need to kill forcefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to kill by graphic interface, just open the Dash and type: System Monitor. Then, select the tab "Process". In that tab, click on the process that you want to stop and click at the "End Process" button, at the bottom of the window. Finally, confirm the finish process in the window that appear.

Comment: This only ends the processes, the OP said that they wanted to kill the process.