# Restart Ubuntu via keyboard

Tags: shortcuts

In win7, when I want to restart computer via keyboard until my operating system hasn't been loaded yet, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

What is equivalent to this command in Ubuntu?

*(Note that I'm not asking for Task manager).*

I wish to restart it if, for example, I pressed <kbd>F10</kbd> but BIOS didn't load successfully so I have to reboot it. I really don't like brute way (using physical shutdown button).

Comment: Do you want to do this as a rescue operation because the mouse does not work, or because you want a convenient way to reboot? Or for some other reason (please specify)?

Comment: To slightly improve upon the not-exactly-perfect-but-still-hopefully-useful workaround of using the terminal, with recent versions of Ubuntu which use systemd (16.04 or possibly earlier), you don't need `sudo` — just `shutdown -r now` will work. (The `-r` flag means restart, and `now` specifies the time.) Depending on which desktop environment you use (Unity, GNOME, XFCE?) you can specify a custom hotkey, for this command.

Comment: @aplaice reboot is shorter

Comment: in KDE, Mate and Cinnamon desktops, Ctrl+Alt+Del will bring up the shut down menu when you can choose to log off, restart or shutdown.

Answer (score 20):

### SysRq REISUB

Responding to your edited original question: I suggest the 'SysRq REISUB' method. This is a way to **reboot linux systems gracefully**, that often works to keep the file system healthy (in contrast to hard poweroff).

<kbd>SysRq</kbd> is often on the <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> key:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> continuously, sometimes the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is involved too (in laptops),
- and then slowly (one key after another) the keys <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> to reboot.

  When you press the 'letter keys' you need *not* specify caps lock or shift.

---

The corresponding sequence to **shut down** the computer gracefully is:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> continuously, sometimes the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is involved too (in laptops),
- and then slowly (one key after another) the keys <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> **<kbd>O</kbd>** to shut down.

  <kbd>B</kbd> 'Boot' is replaced by <kbd>O</kbd> 'Off'.

---

You find more details at the following links,

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)

[How to call up high priority responsive terminal window, even if Xubuntu is hopelessly frozen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968024/how-to-call-up-high-priority-responsive-terminal-window-even-if-xubuntu-is-hope/968054#968054)

---

Edit: The key combo is a bit tricky on some computers. On several Dell laptops, for example Dell Precision M4800, the following works

- Press/hold both <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>
- Press/hold <kbd>Home/Sysrq</kbd>
- *Release* <kbd>Fn</kbd>
- Press key sequence for example <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>

Comment: REISSUB= **R**eboot **E**ven **I**f **S**ystem **U**tterly **B**roken. Might be useful to specify caps lock not necessary.

Comment: I've just tried this - it's working like a charm.

Comment: For me, 'SysRq REISUB' only works with the left Alt key - PrtSc combo. It does not work with the right Alt. The left Alt - PrtSc combo is quite a stretch of the fingers. Laptop: Lenovo Ideapad 15