# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes during restart/shutdown on Asus N552VW

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, shutdown

I have a problem in my Ubuntu 16.04. Every time I try to restart or shutdown it freezes, forcing me to manually use the turn on/off button. This is quite annoying.

I already tried:

1. Changing

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   to

   ```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
   ```
2. Setting `DefaultTimeoutStartSec=5s` and `DefaultTimeoutStopSec=5s`
3. Using Boot Repair, but it froze while working.

It's ASUS N552VW with a dual boot installation with Windows 10.
What else can I try?

Comment: I had the same problem in my ASUS R510V installing Ubuntu 16.04. I tried several configurations of grub, I tried to stop the cups-browsed and reboot. Nothing works for me. SOLUTION: I just change the video driver from open source Intel graphics to NVidia proprietary drivers in the Video Drivers configuration. Since then I can reboot and shut down properly.

Comment: Often you can shut down and reboot gracefully with a **system request sequence** according to the following link, [SysRq REISUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995286/restart-ubuntu-via-keyboard/997223#997223)

Answer (score 0):

Edit boot parameters in GRUB config like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

To this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force apm=power_off"
```

Save the file

Then edit `/etc/modules`:

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

Add this line:

```
apm power_off=1
```

Save the file and update GRUB:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Shutdown:

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```