# My PC doesn't want to make a final rebooting to end up the installation of Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, freeze, reboot, restart

smarty people,

I'm a total noob on OS subject, so I'll be very thankful if you excuse me for the elementary lvl of my question.

I've tried to install the last update desktop version of Ubuntu 17.10, but it refuses to make the last installation (after the settings and all of the questions) to finish the process. I didn't find any similar questions on the Internet, so I've decided that maybe the problem is very unpopular or perhaps I've done something wrong (which is kindda funny, considering how easy should it be).

Anyway, I've downloaded the older version since 16.04.2017, but that didn't fixed the situation. I click on the button "restart" and the desktop freezes with no possibility to click again. The only option available is to shut-down the PC and the whole operation repeat itself all over again.

I've used USB Flash Drive for the booting and I want to make Ubuntu pioneer OS on my PC.

So, where exactly the root of the problem should be? (is in the ground, someone could say, but I've dig the whole place yet)

Comment: The desktop freezing at the very end of the installation has happened to me as well. However, you then *remove the USB before* restarting the computer. The computer will then try to boot from the hard drive where you just installed Ubuntu. If you don't, you will again boot from USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SysRq R E I S U B - graceful reboot

Sometimes, at the very end of the installation, the system justs hangs, does not reboot, does not shut down. This can be caused by a 'race condition', that things cannot be done in the correct sequence.

When this happens it might help with the **SysRq R E I S U B** method. This causes the computer to reboot gracefully (if it can listen to the request).

See more details in the following link and links from it,

[Restart Ubuntu via keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995286/restart-ubuntu-via-keyboard/997223#997223)

> <kbd>SysRq</kbd> is often on the <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> key:
>
> Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> continuously, sometimes
>   the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is involved too (in laptops),
>
> and then slowly (one key after another) the keys <kbd>R</kbd>
>   <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> to
>   reboot.
>
> When you press the 'letter keys' you need *not* specify caps lock or
>   shift.