# Ubuntu doesn't shut down

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

Recently my PC cannot shutdown (Ubuntu 16.04).
Each time I have to turn it off manually using the on/off button on the computer. Restart works fine.

When I try shutting down the usual way, the screen remains blocked as it will shut down in a few seconds. A violet screen with a little Central "ubuntu" word with 5 dots below it, four lit red, one lit white. Running `sudo init 0` and `sudo shutdown now` have the same result.

However, I can restart and open the PC with Windows 7 and then shutdown regularly. What should I do?

Comment: Please describe what you mean by 'Everytime I need to make this manually'. -- I am thinking of the 'SysRq R E I S U B' manual method, [Restart Ubuntu via keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995286/restart-ubuntu-via-keyboard/997223#997223) and 'SysRq R E I S U O' to shut down.

Comment: @sudodus fixed.

Comment: The on/off button of the computer makes a hard shutdown, which might cause corruption of the file system. It is much better to use the 'SysRq R E I S U O' method and get a graceful shutdown. (After using it a few times, you learn it by heart.)

Comment: @David Foerster fixed. For sudo etc I can open a terminal but the keyboard is in Hebrew or upercases in English and I cannot switch language because the switch language icons disappeared from the desktop.

Comment: @David Foerster `sudo shutdown now` has the same result

Comment: Alright, thanks so far. There are a host of possible causes. I recommend that you go through [Shutdown does not power off computer](/q/125844/175814) and try what appears to apply to your situation; you can also take a look at similar linked questions on the right side of it. Please report back with any result that appears to lead to noticeable change during shutdown. Thanks.

Comment: The problem might be a race condition, and in that case it might help with the  'SysRq R E I S U B' and 'SysRq R E I S U O' method. It works with uppercase letters too, and it needs no terminal window or text screen. Did you try it?

Comment: @sudodus Yes, I have tried but maybe due to a lack of understanding concerning this manipulation, this didn't result in nothing

Comment: I had hoped that it would work. It often does, but not always. It seems your computer is too busy/locked by something to listen to the SysRq (system requests). If you boot from a USB boot drive and 'Try Ubuntu', are you able to shut down gracefully? (either the normal way or with 'SysRq R E I S U O' ?

Comment: @sudodus I am sorry but I don't understand you. I tried to upgrade with sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade but there is no effect

Comment: @sudodus for PrScrn REISUB or REISUO this words are printed in a little window at the right down of the screen and after enter pushing both nothing appened

Comment: Did you press both the **`alt`** and **`PrintScreen`** keys all the time and one of the **`R E I S U B`** one after another slowly? If it is a **laptop** you might also need to press the **`Fn`** key like so: Press the three keys  **`Fn`** and **`alt`** and **`PrintScreen`** keys all the time and one of the **`R E I S U B`** one after another slowly. (You need to coordinate a lot of fingers :-P ).

Comment: @sudodus REISUO made the job!  Thanks a lot. If you write it I will accept the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad that you made it work in your computer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Emergency shutdown in a graceful way

- Press both the <kbd>alt</kbd> and <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> keys all the time and one of the <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> keys one after another slowly.
- If it is a **laptop** you might also need to press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key like so:

  Press the three keys <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd> and <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> keys all the time

  and one of the <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> keys one after another slowly.

### Emergency reboot in a graceful way

The corresponding system request sequence for reboot is similar.

<kbd>O</kbd> 'Off' is replaced by <kbd>B</kbd> 'Boot'.

- Press both the <kbd>alt</kbd> and <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> keys or
- in a laptop maybe the three keys <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd> and <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> keys all the time
- The letter key sequence should be <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>

---

See the following links for more details,

[Restart Ubuntu via keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995286/restart-ubuntu-via-keyboard/997223#997223)

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)

Comment: @kouty, you are welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this in terminal

```
init 0
```

Comment: I tried, without results, the result is the same as with standard shutdown

Answer (score 0):

**Try this is in Terminal :**

```
poweroff
```