# Ubuntu 16.04 on Toshiba Satellite fails to restart

Tags: suspend, shutdown, toshiba-satellite

I'm a new Ubuntu user. I've run 16.04 successfully on a Fujitsu Lifebook and have now installed it on a Toshiba Satellite C660.
It runs great but, and here I go into a topic that some might feel has already been exhausted, the Toshiba Satellite refuses to restart after Suspend or Shutdown - until, that is, I force a switch off by pressing the power button.

I have read all the other posts relating to this problem and tried out all the recommended solutions, but because I'm a newbie I can't publish my points of view on these posts until I have racked up a 10 point reputation. In my case, with the Toshiba Satellite, I've discovered that by unplugging the battery charger before closing the lid or otherwise going to Suspend or Shutdown and likewise before restarting, the laptop wakes up/starts up perfectly normally every time.

I wouldn't know where to start in finding a fault in the software. I'm just a lowly engineer. I just hope my observations might go a small way towards helping someone out there who has the knowledge to sort out a solution to the software.

Comment: "I've discovered that by unplugging the battery charger before closing the lid or otherwise going to Suspend or Shutdown and likewise before restarting." What do you mean by this?

Comment: Please don't put the question and answer together in the same question. Instead you can post an answer to your own question and even click the checkmark beside it to mark it as the accepted answer two days after posting it.

Comment: The [SysRq REISUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995286/restart-ubuntu-via-keyboard/997223#997223) method can often help in such situations. This way you can avoid a hard poweroff and instead reboot or shut down gracefully, which reduces the risk to damage the file system.

Comment: Thank you to all who responded so quickly. In answer to Bajiru:

Comment: Thank you all who replied so quickly: In answer to Bajiru: The machine has the problem that it will not re-start normally after a normal Shutdown or Suspend when it is connected to Mains Power via the Battery Charger. If the Battery Charger is disconnected prior to Shutdown or Suspend and disconnected again before re-starting the machine will properly wake up/re-start every time. This applies no matter what method is used to Suspend/Shutdown. ie. From on-screen or by closing/opening the laptop screen/lid. The Charger can be used as normal while working or while the Laptop is idle.

Comment: In reply to karel: I wasn't aware that I had asked a question and answered it. My intention was to publish my observation that the use or not of the Mains Lead/Battery Charger seems to be a cause of the laptop's inability to re-start properly after Suspend or Shutdown. My question was (is). Is there anyone with the relevant knowledge able to use my observation of the Toshiba Satellite's behaviour to make a necessary correction to the software.

Answer (score -2):

My Toshiba Satellite C660 running Linux Mint failed to resume from suspend.

The way I fixed it was by removing `intel-microcode` using:

```
sudo apt purge intel-microcode
```

It worked perfectly. If not, run:

```
sudo apt install intel-microcode
```