# My computer doesn't turn off

Tags: 14.04

My question is about my home station which doesn't turn off, and return the following message:

```
Wait-for-state stop/waiting
*Stopping rsync daemon rsync 
*Speech-dispatcher disabled: edit /etc/default/speech_dispatcher
*asking all remaining processes to terminate...
```

Comment: Instead of 'hard shutdown', which may corrupt the file system, you can **shut down or reboot gracefully** with system request hotkey sequences, 'SysRq REISUB' and 'SysRq REISUO'. See this link: [Restart Ubuntu via keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995286/restart-ubuntu-via-keyboard/997223?s=3|12.7605#997223)

Answer (score 0):

User <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>  or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>. 
It seems that this happened during shutdown and a daemon could not be stopped.

Otherwise you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Function</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>.

If nothing helps power off your station by pressing your power button until. The next time linux starts up it will check your file system and correct it.

You have to correct your speech_dispatcher config.