# Shutting down/restarting Ubuntu makes the computer hang on a blank screen

Tags: shutdown

I successfully installed Ubuntu on a Lenovo 720 15". When I go to reboot or shut down, it just hangs on a black screen for a very long time. Does anyone else have this problem? Any ideas as to how to fix it? Unfortunately it does not seem to be outputting any errors to the screen.

Comment: Until you solve the problem you can reboot/shutdown gracefully with the SysRq REISUB method according to this link, [Restart Ubuntu via keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995286/restart-ubuntu-via-keyboard/997223#997223)