# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at shutdown

Tags: xubuntu, shutdown, 18.04

I am having this weird problem in Ubuntu 18.04. My laptop gets stuck at the shutdown screen every time I use shutdown and I have to manually press the power button for 5 seconds to turn the machine off.

Before 18.04, I was using Ubuntu 16.04 and it never got stuck at shutdown.

Any fix for this?

Comment: Does it freeze on a black screen?

Comment: Until the problem is solved it may help with [SysRq REISUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995286/restart-ubuntu-via-keyboard/997223?s=1|31.0845#997223). It will reboot the computer gracefully. The corresponding shutdown/poweroff is SysRq REISUO

Comment: It freezes when it shows ubuntu logo

Comment: Have you tried  SysRq REISUB or  SysRq REISUO yet? In that case, does it help?

Comment: How long did you wait?  I see a 90 second CUPS timeout sometimes on 18.04 shutdown.

Comment: @ubfan1 Occasionally on 16.04 my shutdown would be inhibited for 90 seconds or so too.

Comment: I am not sure what happened now, but somehow it has shutting down properly. But now I am seeing regular system crashes. No idea what is happening here :)

Comment: I got same problem with 18.04. In my case it not showing the logo page but shows shutdown process.  In shutdown it printing a lot of error on nouveau (nvidia VGA)

Comment: Tried all the new solutions in the comments but still same. :/

Comment: Same problem here in my Acer Travelmate laptop. What I noticed is (1) if I turn off after short use (without leaving idle with screen locks) it turns off fine. (2) Turning off after unlocking the screen hangs (in this case I have tried `sudo poweroff` also but still hangs).  (3) Once I noticed windows style `install update and shutdown` thing... Not sure if it tried to install updates during shutdown process. But I didn't find any updates to be installed when checked. I  hope I have given some clue for someone to investigate deeper on this issue. :)

Comment: look for errors in file `/var/log/syslog` after you boot back up

Comment: On Lubuntu 20.04 shutdown and reboot both hang on a Lubuntu splash screen.  I hit the ESC key and was dropped into some text output. The screen is filled with lines with timestamps and among them shows: `watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 22s! [systemd-shutdow:1].` and `CPU: 3 PID: 1 Comm: systemd-shutdow Tainted: G  L 5.4.0-54-generic #60-Ubuntu` It seems to be stuck in some kind of loop and repeats every 20 seconds or so.  This is with a brand new install.

Answer (score 24):

While none of the other answers here helped for me (encountering the same problem), I fixed it by switching from the X.org graphics driver to the propietary nvidia driver that is recommended under software&updates. Since then, reboot works flawlessly.

My setup: Asus G Series Laptop G501VW, with Nvidia 960M graphics card.

To do this:

- open Software&Updates (top left: Click on activities and type "software". Pick software&updates)
- go to "additional drivers"
- select a nvidia driver instead of the X.org driver
- reboot the system

Comment: For me, no solution has worked till now. Whatsoever I tried, I might have to switch back to previous version as this issue has no solution.

Comment: I'm using Elementary OS Juno with the same hardware (ASUS ROG G501VW). And I can confirm this solution has solved the problem.

Comment: This one also worked for me - desktop with GeForce GT640. I've switched to nvidia-driver-390.

Comment: It solved the problem for me as well. Asus Zenbook with Nvdia GTX 1050

Comment: This worked for MSI GL Laptop with GTX 1050Ti, Ubuntu additionally prompted setting a password for secure boot and using it on next boot.

Comment: I found too many nouveau related issues in /var/log/syslog. So I used sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall to install NVidia drivers. It works fine now. 
Had to undergo enrolling new MOK procedure. Xiaomi Notebook Pro.

Comment: its not immediately obvious how to do the above

Comment: Thanks, worked for asus a509fj,, first time install in this notebook..

Comment: Finally! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 15):

Same problem here on my laptop. After some observation, I found out that it has something to do with power saving mode specially automatic suspend.

Go to `Settings > Power` then turn off all `Automatic Suspend` options. Also choose `Blank screen` to `Never`.

Till Ubuntu team will figure out why suspend mode is interfering with shutdown process, this solved my problem.

Hope this helps

Comment: I will try this :)

Comment: This fixed the problem. Hope ubuntu will send a fix soon

Comment: Also this solution does not work for me.

Comment: This worked for me: change Bios Graphic card from Discrete to UMA : https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Legion-Y520-Freeze-when-try-to-shutdown-or-restart-after-fresh/td-p/4162896

Comment: There seems to be multiple cause for this. I recently bought a desktop and had dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Faced the same issue regardless of power settings I suggested earlier.

However when I try to `sudo poweroff` from terminal it works as expected (shuts down fast without any delay)

Not sure if any issue with permissions during the shutdown process.

Comment: I'm seriously surprised - this actually worked for me

Comment: On ubuntu 20.04, now I can lock the screen again...Still cannot reboot/power off (now black screen and nothing happens..before it was just stuck). 
To note that this happens to me only when I use a dell usb dock station to attach 2 additional monitors to the laptop. I have updated nvidia and displaylink drivers

Comment: Solved it for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Fixed it for me on ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 6):

Try a couple of sudo reboots from terminal to see if it clears things up:
1st to try, reboot without writing wtmp file:

```
sudo reboot -d
```

If that reboots successfully then try your natural close down. If it doesn't reboot, try forced reboot:

```
sudo reboot -f
```

If this was an upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04, it may be worth considering a clean install.

Comment: I will give it a try if it happens again.

Comment: I had 16.04 (stucking on shutdown) upgraded to 18.04 - the same stuff. <br>Tried clean install of 18.04 - the same problem.

Comment: I did not solved yet, but the first option does not work, instead the second does. The problem still persist on simply restart from terminal, as it keep freezing

Comment: The second worked for me too: sudo reboot -f

Comment: sudo reboot -f works for me. It also reboots from lock screen with no problem.

Comment: this also worked for me

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem and in my case it seems to be related to the **Intel Bay trail CPU** which is causing some firmware bugs.

Anyway I have a solution which isn't the best but good enough for now

**Solution:**

- Open the terminal and run

  ```
  sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
  ```
- Edit `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash"` so that it says

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
  ```
- Save and exit, and write the changes to GRUB's actual config file:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Restart your computer forcefully one last time

*Let me know if it worked or when you have a better solution*

Comment: I've been stuck with this for a few months, upgrading to every new kernel, but this finally worked! Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not worked for me. On second reboot, it does check something, with showing that is all good but then Ubuntu start normally, but on reboot freeze again.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Fr reference, my notebokk has an Intel HD Graphics 4400 chip.

Comment: This worked for me too.

Answer (score 2):

There are scores of scripts that run when you shutdown. I'm still on 16.04 and for me these are the ones in `/etc/rc0.d` (which are really links to `/etc/init.d`). One of them may have a long delay set in what it does for `stop`.

AFAIK these scripts are run in alphabetical order, so you can insert a few that would just log their execution somewhere, helping you spot where the delay is.

Comment: You are right. Stopping MySQL server took about 10-15 minutes on my Ubuntu 18.04. Really don't know why it is so long. [Screen photo](https://i.postimg.cc/YSFPYg7d/photo-2019-04-25-18-21-23.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem on a brand new ASUS N705u.
Found had to do with how the video driver installs which causes a conflict with the "secure boot" function of the BIOS.
**Solution:** Turn the "secure boot" function off until other solution will become available.

Comment: Do you have any more information, like which video driver causes the problem, and how it causes a problem with secure boot that inhibits shutdown?

Comment: That laptop comes with a NVIDIA GeForce MX150 graphics card. During installation of Ubuntu 18.04 a remark is made that a third party driver is needed which requires safe boot option to be turned off. It also asks for a password to allow safe boot disabling process. However, this password is never being asked for and it appears safe boot remains on regardless. (BIOS -ASUS 302).

Comment: Also after initial installation a third party driver "GP107M" is being downloaded and installed.  A second computer - same model, that initial question doesn't come up during install once safe boot is disabled in BIOS

Comment: UPDATE: As mentioned above got two new computers with new Kubuntu 18.04 installs. Both kept playing up either on shutdown or then suddenly during the final stages of starting up. - Turns out it's the WIFI Manager ! Turn my WIFI Repeater off - all good. But if it's on those problems are back!

Comment: In my case, Wifi router was not even switching off/on even when pressing the Wifi button.

Answer (score 1):

My system is an older Dell Dimension E521 desktop, dual core, with Lubuntu 18.04, 64-bit.

In `/etc/default/grub`, I removed `acpi=off` and the system started behaving normally.

More specifically, I changed this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noapic acpi=off"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noapic"
```

Now my box once again shuts down when I tell it to, and is refreshingly responsive.

Comment: do you suffer from dyslexia, or are these actually 3 different yet valid arrangements of letters A, C, P and I?

Comment: @Adam - "ACPI, known as a Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL) in embedded computing, is an abstraction layer between the operating system, platform firmware and hardware. This allows the OS and the platform to evolve independently. ...  " and  "Most (all) Intel-MP compliant SMP boards have the so-called ‘IO-APIC’, which is an enhanced interrupt controller."   and yes, I just checked and the last 'noapci' should be 'noapic'.     Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i have the driver nouveau, Ubuntu 18.04

Solution:

Open terminal

sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_rev_override=1 nouveau.modeset=0"

sudo update-grub

This solved the issue for me, now i can shutdown and restart

Answer (score 1):

1. open terminal and type : **sudoedit /etc/default/grub**
2. change **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"** into **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"**
3. save the file
4. **sudo update-grub**

that's it ... it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after a kernel upgrade. Shutdown/restart command was working smoothly before the upgrade. But started freezing after the upgrade.  I attempted all fixes that are mentioned here and various other forums but nothing seemed to work. So I started installing various versions kernels and checked up shutdown command with different kernels and found that my machine freezes for all kernels greater than the following version:

```
linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic
```

My PC has the following specifications:

```
Intel Core i5-8250U
NVIDIA Geforce MX150 with 2 GB VRAM
```

I had the same issue when I installed Kali along with Ubuntu. Searching for its solutions I found it was probably  a GPU issue and disabling the generic nouveau driver might fix it.

I applied the solution given below for kali:

> 1. Check your apt sources as per https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories
> 2. Run `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`
> 3. Create the following file: `/etc/modprobe.d/nouveau-blacklist.conf`
> 4. Edit that file and add only one line that says `blacklist nouveau`
> 5. Reboot your PC.
> 6. Run `apt-get install libcuda1 libnvidia-ml1 --no-install-recommends -y`
> 7. Dn not reboot your PC at this point. You must edit one file before doing so or your GDM greeter won't work
> 8. Edit the file `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf` and comment out the second line that says `remove nvidia-current rmmod nvidia nvidia-uvm`,
>      or delete that line. Make sure that file has only one line that says
>      `alias nvidia nvidia-current`
> 9. Run `apt install nvidia-kernel-amd64 nvidia-kernel-common nvidia-kernel-dkms`
> 10. Reboot your PC.

https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?27173-Solution-for-Reboot-Issues

and it worked for my kali. Applied the same for my Ubuntu, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Imad's suggestion: change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

into

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

This is the only solution that works consistently for me. Will take that back.  Nothing on this page works for me.  AMD Turion X64 Duo Core Toshiba A215

Answer (score 1):

For my Lenovo E580 the solution was adding the open ubuntu graphics drivers from https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: This worked for me though not immediately but after several updates spanning several days my Kubuntu 18.03.3 LTS finally restarted and shutdown gracefully

Answer (score 0):

After doing more testing on two computers found it is in fact the Wifi Manager and the way it connects / identifies with the network. On two identical computers the problem disappears once the Wifi manager is turned off. Also tried USB Wifi dongle which worked on one computer but once again caused system to freeze at moment of registration on network. Have already tried a different Wifi manager with improved conditions.
Also noticed in BIOS if secure boot is disabled then there is a list of drivers rejected bi BIOS due to security issues. Perhaps this is the underlying issue related to the Wifi manager.

Comment: Temporary fix:  a) Turn Wifi off     or   b) Try disabling original Wifi Manager and install different one instead.

Comment: The unsecure driver theory and wifi makes sense to me. In my case, I installed a modified WiFi driver and since then the problem began. Will be trying disabling secureboot.

Answer (score 0):

I had success turning off usb 3.0 driver in bios, not ideal, but it is fixed until more research is done.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that it happens to me too if i use my laptop for more than 10 hours, the gnome-shell uses more memory with time starting from 200 and going up to 500, firefox too starts with memory usage of 150 and goes all the way up to 900, restarting my laptop every 4 to 5 hours solved the issue of shutdown freezing for me I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing 18.04 on a Fujitsu Scaleo.

During the install I had to add the `acpi=off` to be able to install Ubuntu because of a conflict with the Intel 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller.
After that Ubuntu would just halt at `System Halted` when I shut it down.

In the end I changed the BIOS `ACPI Suspend Type` from S3 to Auto. I did this in Power Management.
After this the PC would power down and I could even remove the `acpi=off` from Grub.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with ubuntu 18.04. I installed nvidia driver and now it works fine. Install your driver as described in https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but for me, when I remove whole "quite splash acpi=off" and leave it blank, the issue is gone. Now my PC boot and reboot smoothly

Comment: Hi!  This is truly more of a comment rather than an answer.  Your 'fix' is probably the `acpi=off` part - the `quiet` suppresses boot messages, and the `splash` displays a pretty image during boot.

Comment: Yeah I'm just a newbie. But tried all above solution but it didn't work for me. So I tried remove all three of it and magically it reboot and boot without stuck.

Comment: Nothing works like success!  Why did your system have that boot option set?

Comment: It is there by default

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem yesterday while installing 18.04
As mentioned earlier in the post. updating NVIDIA drivers. There are several ways of doing this but i recommend following steps

1. find your graphics card name and download it.
2. run following commands
   sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install build-essential libc6:i386
3. reboot
4. on start run sudo telinit 3
5. use terminal to navigate to Downloads folder and type 
   sudo ./the driver download file
6. after install: sudo reboot

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by this way below(dell laptop with Ubuntu 18.04):

Open the Terminal and input this line: `sync && sudo sync`  press Enter, and continue to input the second line: `sudo shutdowm -h now` or `sudo reboot` press Enter. If it works well. and then you can normally shutdowm or reboot your system as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a pain.

In my case, **turning acpi off in grub**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noacpi"
```

then

```
sudo update-grub
```

and

```
reboot -d
```

did the trick.

Suspend mode and shutdown are behaving normally again.
I don't know what caused the problem in the first place: I was having issues while using Unity, Ubuntu would freeze when working on a specific text file. So I installed XFCE to see whether it was a UI problem or a hardware (disk-related) problem. Disks were supposedly clean and checked. With XFCE I no longer had freezes with the txt file, but shutdown and suspend would not work anymore...