# Laptop won't power-off after shutdown

Tags: boot, grub2, shutdown

so I did software updates yesterday (the software updater popped up and I followed to instructions) and went on to watch a movie. Then I used to GUI to press "Power Off", closed it and went to sleep. Just now I realised that it was on the entire night, but the screen was black. It wasn't reacting to any key-stroke or clicking on the mousepad-thingie, so I kept pressing the power button to force shut it off.

I thought it is a onetime-thing, but I went to investigate. Neither "Power Off" or "Restart" work properly. The screen goes black, but the keyboard LEDs aswell as the power-LED are still lit and the fan turns up sometimes.

Some Info:

Ubuntu Version 18.04.4 LTS

Dual-Boot with Windows 10

ThinkPad E495 (maybe 4 months old)

Things I've tried:

Using the command prompt to `shutdown now` aswell as `init 0` , `reboot -p` and `sudo systemctl poweroff` -> No changes

Using the command prompt to `sudo update-grub` -> No changes

Pressing e in the bootup menu in grub to change `linux /boot/vmlinux/something-something ... quiet splash` and add `acpi=force` -> No changes

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried `sudo systemctl poweroff`? Let me know by commenting here with @AkibAzmain

Comment: What about " reboot -p " or " init 0 " ?

Comment: @AkibAzmain None of those work any different. Screen goes black, Power- and Keyboard-LED still lit up. Tried reboot-p and init 0 aswell.

Comment: Same problem with Lenovo Ideapad340

Answer (score 2):

Read This [Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029068/ubuntu-18-04-stuck-at-shutdown):

Same problem here on my laptop. After some observation, I found out that it has something to do with power saving mode specially automatic suspend.

Go to `Settings > Power` then turn off all `Automatic Suspend` options. Also choose `Blank screen` to `Never`.

Till Ubuntu team will figure out why suspend mode is interfering with shutdown process, this solved my problem.

Hope this helps

This post also mention about Display Drivers related solution. Check if it matches with yours.

Comment: This didn't change anything for me sadly.