# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't shutdown when power off button is pressed

Tags: shutdown

this is my first time asking a question here and if anyone could help me solve it, I will be very grateful (I am quite beginner). I have Ubuntu 18.04 in my HP Pavilion Laptop 15-cw0002la with AMD Ryzen 5 processor. When I press the power off button or even in the terminal typping "sudo shutdown -r now", my laptop's screen is off, but the light is still on and it keeps running, then I need to press the power button for 5 seconds to turn the laptop off.

I have tried everything in the following web pages and still doesn't work.
[Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029068/ubuntu-18-04-stuck-at-shutdown)
https://unixmen.com/fix-shutdown-power-computer-ubuntu-14-04/

Specially changing

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"`

and to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noapic"`

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema, it says ´F.35´

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: @Pilot6 I forgot to tell, I ended up installing Debian 10, sorry, I am very new at this

Comment: So, this question is now off-topic at this site. Changing distros rarely helps to solve hardware problems.

Comment: @Pilot6 okok good to know, thank you!!!

Comment: Please don't change the question drastically once you've solved an issue. You can always ask a new question. I have rolled back your edits.

Comment: @kulfy Sorry, now I know it, it won't happen again. Do you know where can I ask a question about Debian? I have searched, but there is no ask debian hahaha, I asked it on UNIX & LINUX, hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HP Pavilion Laptop 15-cw0002la

You have BIOS F.35.

There's a newer BIOS available, F.42, dated Dec 11, 2019, and can be downloaded [here](https://support.hp.com/lamerica_nsc_carib-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-pavilion-15-cw0000-laptop-pc/20284015/model/22399605).

**Note**: Confirm that I've got the correct web page for your model #.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Comment: I have already installed the new BIOS on the windows dual boot side, but now when I enter to Ubuntu still can't power off, but now there is also no wifi or sound. Help :(

Comment: @Davidxieli Did you undo the changes that you made `/etc/default/grub` and then `sudo update-grub`? Did you reset the BIOS and then check individual BIOS settings to assure that they're correct?

Comment: I am going to ask it in a question apart, thanks a lot

Comment: @Davidxieli Why not finish this question? Check the settings in my prior comment first.

Comment: already checked, all good, the only problem left is that it doesn't detect the wifi, only ethernet works

Comment: @Davidxieli Check to make sure that the wifi is enabled in the new BIOS, and enabled in the wifi network settings panel. Also edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `dkms status` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Does the computer properly shutdown now?

Comment: Ok I am on it, and yes it properly shutdown now, but now there is also no sound again

Comment: @Davidxieli Oh, you completely changed your question. Wrong thing to do. My answer is null now. Although, since it solved the original shutdown question, you should probably accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks. What version Ubuntu is this?