# Shutdown Ubuntu by script

Tags: kernel, scripts, shutdown, system

I need some way to override shutting down of Ubuntu, because it freezes on shutdown. It's kernel problem (I tried very different distros).
System passes "reached target shutdown" and little after it freeze.

Comment: One way to work around this problem and still shut down gracefully is the **SysRq REISUO** method. See the following link, [Restart Ubuntu via keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995286/restart-ubuntu-via-keyboard/997223#997223)

Comment: If it's a *kernel problem*, perhaps you should look into that instead...

Comment: This problem is often said to be caused by a race condition (that affects some computer and kernel combinations). It may disappear after a kernel upgrade, but I think it is difficult to solve unless you downgrade to an older kernel or replace some hardware. If you can shutdown gracefully and avoid corrupting the file system, you can live with it.

Comment: @heemayl who to look there: what do you mean exactly - all kernels starting from 4.10.x and highter have that problem, so if you taliking about changing kernel then it's not an option.

Comment: @sudodus all kernels starting from 4.10.x and highter have that problem, so upgrading isn't an option and I doubt about downgrade of kernel cause some packages of new system can be not compatible with older kernel.

Comment: @sudodus  REISUO and REISUB do not work. If I reach "target shutdown" it means it will not corrupt anything, right ?

Comment: I am not sure but I think you are right about that. Anyway, if the computer shuts down (electrically), when you press quickly on the power button, things should be OK. If you have to press the power button for around 4 seconds, things may be worse.