# Sudden high CPU usage followed by Input/Output error

Tags: bash, lenovo, cpu, cpu-load, i3-wm

First a little bit of information about my system:

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 with encryption while installing

DE: i3wm (probably doesn't have to with this, because the same problem appears in Gnome)

Hardware: Lenovo T470

Since about three days I'm encountering the problem, that all of a sudden the CPU usage rises to about 100% (sometimes 98%). Shortly after the rise nothing works anymore and bash returns an "Input/Output error" and I have to power off by removing the battery...

Now I know Input/Output errors usually happen because the hard drive is full, but mine isn't even remotely full (at about 7% - checked with df).

Here is the output of journalctl of the last two boots:
[Journal](https://github.com/andoril1/pastes/blob/master/journalctl-output-last-two-boots.txt)

I don't understand what's going on and I already had to repeat some work because of this, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which process takes so much CPU according to e.g `top` command?

Comment: @jarno: I don't know, because I can't start top anymore if this happens. Do you happen to know about a monitoring tool I could use to further analyse this?

Comment: Use [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/997223/21005) instead of removing battery. You could run `top -b >output.txt` to save top's output in the file output.txt, and check afterwards what was going on.

Comment: Thank you so far. Didn't know about the SysRQ key^^

I'll edit the question as soon as I have some top output that could help.

Comment: @jarno Hey. It's me again. The problem didn't happen again, so I guess I'm fine now? However what shall I do with my question? Mark it as solved? Let it stay open?

Comment: Maybe the issue relates to some job running in background occasionally. I suggest you keep this open.