# What is the equivalent of Ctrl+Alt+Delete for when Ubuntu 18.04 locks up?

Tags: shortcut-keys, lockup

Occasionally Ubuntu 18.04 will freeze. In windows there is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> shortcut. What do you do in Ubuntu?

Also, I saw that there were other questions like this, but it says they are duplicates and they don't point to the answer.

One of the "duplicates" had lots of suggestions of other things you could do in Ubuntu instead of those keys, like how to stop a certain process using the terminal. However, when the whole system freezes, you can't really start the terminal.

Is there a keyboard shortcut equivalent in Ubuntu or do I just have to turn the power off?

Comment: You can often use the **SysRq REISUB** method according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995286/restart-ubuntu-via-keyboard/997223#997223)

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need.  Thanks.  I don't hope that I get to try it out soon but I'll have it ready when I do.

Comment: Is the "waht" in the title a typo?

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes

Comment: Only SUB from REISUB now work.

Answer (score 1):

There are some key combinations.

One is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to `tty`, where you can stop processes, etc.

Another will be to force a reboot if nothing else helps:

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd> and type SUB on the keyboard.

Comment: Isn't Ubuntu's graphical user interface on `tty1` these days? If Ctrl+Alt+F1 doesn't work, try Ctrl+Alt+F2 instead.