# Reboot freezes at end of Ubuntu 18.04.3 installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, dell, live-usb

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu 18.04.3 on my Dell G3 3579 gaming laptop.

The installation went normally, but when I need to reboot the system to finish the installation the laptop freezes. This image is from the reboot initialization.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

My laptop specs are:

```
i7-8750H
16GB RAM
GTX 1050Ti 4 GB
256 GB ssd + 1 tb hdd
```

I've tried many solutions and tutorials. Nothing is working. Is anyone having solution for it.

Comment: looks like a read only drive? weird

Comment: A lot people are having same problem.

Comment: Have you tried [SysRq R E I S U B](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995286/restart-ubuntu-via-keyboard/997223#997223)  in order to get a graceful reboot? The problem might be caused by a race condition, which can happen with some computers.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that too. Same result

Comment: Try again, if a laptop this time with `Fn` + `alt` + `PrintScreen` pressed all the time while you press the keys R E I S U B slowly (one per second). Do **not** press shift to get upper case.

Comment: @SarthakPurohit I never seen this problem, been using Ubuntu since 2006, it is related to Dells only?

Comment: @BookOfZeus   no, it's actually a Nvidia graphics card problem. For a trail solution they included "Install(safe graphics)" in Ubunutu 19.04 installation. That even works but that mode is still isn't available in LTS version.

Comment: @SarthakPurohit interesting, good find