# Ubuntu keyboard and mouse suddenly stopped working

Tags: boot

I played Skyrim via Wine, then it started lagging so hard that I rebooted computer holding Power button. Then, when I turned it on, on a login page keyboard and mouse were working. I typed password, and after logging in noticed that keyboard and mouse are not working. I tried to reboot (same situation), tried recovery mode. Nothing worked. What I need to do?
Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: how does this relate to Ubuntu? Please [edit] your question after reading [ask]

Comment: @User24601 I am using Ubuntu

Comment: version? please [edit] your question rather than add comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can type on the login screen, then there should be a way to workable shell.

[This article](https://techwiser.com/fix-keyboard-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04/) has more on it.

From the description of the error, I would doublecheck for hardware problems, like e.g. a dying SSD. I would look for I/O errors [in system logs](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/viewing-and-monitoring-log-files#1-overview).

If there are indeed signs of significant disk problems, then, before anything else, I would backup all important documents/files/etc from the disk, while being booted from a live USB.

After important files are backed up, I would also consider a filesystem check and possibly repair with `fsck` (on the unmounted `/` partition), again, from a live USB.

Then, regarding the keyboard / mouse:

Recently I have seen a few places that recommended

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all`

or

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all`

read these: [Keyboard and mouse unresponsive after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483416/keyboard-and-mouse-unresponsive-after-suspend),

and the [aforementioned article](https://techwiser.com/fix-keyboard-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04/).

I have no personal experience with this procedure, just offering for consideration.

Finally, regarding "rebooted computer holding Power button", I recommend googling and learning how to reboot with the ["REISUB" method](https://askubuntu.com/a/997223/1157519). It's not always effective, but when it is, it's nicer on the (file)system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how should I enter the commands if my keyboard and mouse are dead?

Comment: Re-read the first two lines of my answer. Your inputs seem to not work after the graphical interface loaded; but before they do. Therefore, you should be able to navigate to a command line interface (not the graphical), where you can issue commands. This has more detailed info: https://askubuntu.com/a/859640/1157519

Comment: Also this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode | Get to grub menu > pick advanced options for Ubuntu > pick recovery mode > pick 'drop to root shell' > follow the instructions, if any.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer provided by [Levente](https://askubuntu.com/a/1302442/1041981), the following commands may come in handy:

**1. Enable a disabled input device**

- Get the ids of the devices: `xinput --list`
- Enable the device with id=n: `xinput enable n`

**2. Remove/add modules to Linux kernel**

- Remove touchpad driver: `modprobe -r psmouse`
- Add it again: `modprobe psmouse`
- For keyboard, I think you must use *atkbd* instead of *psmouse*

**NOTE** that you need to run the commands as super user, I mean, *sudo*.