# Mouse cursor not displaying and keyboard not working after update

Tags: keyboard, mouse, amd-graphics, gpu, amdgpu

After updating to Ubuntu 22.10, my cursor has stopped showing on my desktop environment. It is still there since I can still move windows around, it is just invisible.
The mouse is visible in the lock screen, dock and the app screen.
If I open an app, the keyboard will not input anything I type. **ctrl + alt + f4** still works, but **ctrl + alt + t** to open the terminal does not.

I have tried adding "nomodeset" to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`

which fixed my mouse and keyboard issue, but prevented my GPU fans from running.

The mouse and keyboard still work in recovery mode, but my gpu fans do not.

I have tried updating my keyboard drivers as suggested by some other users, but it hasn't changed anything as far as I'm aware.

Any help appreciated, I am so confused :(

***Edit One***
inputting `inxi -G` to the terminal yields this result:

````
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.3 driver:
    X: loaded: vesa unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon gpu: N/A
    resolution: 1680x1050~77Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 14.0.1 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa
    22.1.0-devel```
````

Comment: Could you paste the output of `inxi -G` into your question? And try to log out, select the cog icon and choose XServer Session instead of "wayland" and log in again

Comment: You need to give us a lot more info. What desktop? What make and model of computer? What graphics card or GPU? What driver for that GPU? Have you done a full update? Have you installed any drivers suggested by the "Software & Drivers" program? I do not know what "update keyboard drivers" means but that is not a real thing, so what did you do, based on what advice?

Comment: @LiamProven Sorry! I rushed to post this question last night and didn't even think to add all those details. 
I'm not entirely sure what you mean by asking what desktop, but if it helps, I'm using GNOME.
I have an AMD radeon RX 6600, and I've been using the drivers provided on AMD's website [here] (https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers). 
I did a full update several days ago, but I can attempt doing another one.

Comment: @LiamProven I have not installed any drivers suggested by "Softwear & Updates", since it just tells me that there are no additional drivers available.
And my apologies, I mispoke when I said update, I meant reinstall. I used advice from [this post] (https://askubuntu.com/a/1302442/1657684)

Comment: @kanehekili Ive posted the output into my main post. Ive tried logging out, but I'm not sure where to find the cog icon. I assume it is on the login page, but I don't see it

Comment: @kanehekili Oops, user error, I've found it, and my mouse and keyboard now work. Thank you so much

Comment: Great and thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Log out, select the cog icon and choose XServer Session instead of "wayland" and log in again.
Thank you to @kanehekili :)