# How to reboot or restart Ubuntu 22.04 using shortcut keys

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I tried to restart Ubuntu 22.04. In Windows, I used to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>, but if I use the same shortcut keys in Ubuntu, it just logs me out

Answer (score 1):

Without any alterations to do what you want you need to switch to a console 1st (control-alt-f1) and then control-alt-delete will do a reboot. No need to login.

The grafeful way to reboot is SysRq with the letters REISUB. See https://askubuntu.com/a/997223/15811 for more on that.

If you want control-alt-delete to do a reboot you need to open "keyboard shortcuts" and connect "reboot" to those keys. See [keyboard-shortcuts-set](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en) on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

#1: Open Settings and go to Keyboard [image]

#2: Click on Keyboard shortcuts (it should be the option at the bottom)[image] and then scroll down until you see Custom shortcut (again, the option at the bottom), click it.

#3: Click add and name it, the command is reboot, set your desired shortcut such as Ctrl + Alt + Delete.[image]
[image]

WARNING: CTRL+ALT+DELETE is already set for log out. If you use that shortcut then log out will not work unless you change it to something else.

Comment: If this was useful please consider tagging this answer as the solution, it will help others and also me, thanks.