# Infinite Shutdown (vanilla Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: shutdown, reboot, restart

[Specs](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/mjHYpb)

So whenever I either shutdown or restart Ubuntu, it goes on forever. At least, I've left it 10+ mins and it shouldn't be taking that long so I'm assuming that leaving it for hours wouldn't give me any luck.

I am also dual-booting Windows 10 (both Win & Ubuntu partitions are 1.5TB if that matters). I can shutdown and restart just fine on Windows.

I am using Nvidia 384.111 proprietary drivers and according to my Additional Drivers, I'm using "Processor microcode firmware for AMD CPUs from amd64-microcode".

[Here](https://pastebin.com/Q8e95HWk) are my past few syslogs (or the shutdown parts, at least).

Let me know if you need any more info, and I'll add it to this post. Also, note that I'm new to Ubuntu (and Linux in general) so I'd appreciate it if things were explained in a noob-friendly way. Thank you!

Edit: Thought I'd just clarify that things are stalling on the splash screen where it says Ubuntu and has the dots underneath it with the purple background.

Edit edit: `sudo shutdown -h now` has the same effect as clicking the shutdown or restart button.

Edit edit edit: Fixed! I did [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132143/stuck-on-reboot-and-shutdown/135568#135568) and it worked. In the meantime, I used [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968024/how-to-call-up-high-priority-responsive-terminal-window-even-if-xubuntu-is-hope/968054#968054) in order to work around the issue.

Edit edit edit: False alarm. Okay, so what happens is that sometimes, the splash screen doesn't show. Whenever it does, it goes on forever. I believe there is a correlation between how long I leave my system on for and whether or not I get a splash screen (in which case I'll get the issue).

Comment: This is a work-around until you find a solution, so that you can make a soft reboot or shutdown: The 'SysRq REISUB' method: https://askubuntu.com/questions/968024/how-to-call-up-high-priority-responsive-terminal-window-even-if-xubuntu-is-hope/968054#968054

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep that in mind until this gets fixed.