# Application in Ubuntu Virtual Machine is frozen

Tags: suspend, shutdown, vmware

My computer is windows, but I am working in an Ubuntu Virtual Machine.  I was doing some work in an application, and then it froze on me.  I tried suspending the VM and reopening it, but the application was still frozen.

Should I choose Shut Down or some other option?  I just want to be able to re-load the VM and not have to deal with the frozen application anymore.  I already saved all my work before the application froze, so that is not a concern.

Comment: you can close the app with xkill or kill.

Comment: How would I use that command?  Also, would there be any consequences of using that command, other than simply closing the application?

Comment: You would loose data, but should be fine. Open a terminal and run `xkill` put the crossbones on the app and click. If that does not work `killall name_of_app` or `kill -9 PID` to get the PID of the app you need to run `ps axf | grep <app name>` . See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/104903/how-do-i-kill-processes-in-ubuntu