# How should properly stop x0vncserver?

Tags: vnc, remote, kill

I use x0vncserver to connect to my ubuntu display. I start it with `/usr/bin/x0vncserver -display :0`. I can see it running with `pidof x0vncserver`.

I have also seen that the [proper way](https://superuser.com/questions/549386/what-is-the-correct-way-to-kill-a-vncsession-in-linux) to stop vncserver is to use `vncserver -kill :xx` command.

Is there a similar command to properly stop x0vncserver or one should just use `killall x0vncserver` to stop it?

When trying `sudo systemctl stop x0vncserver`, I got:

```
Failed to stop x0vncserver.service: Unit x0vncserver.service not loaded.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [killing by PID](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104903/how-do-i-kill-processes-in-ubuntu) is the way to go.

First obtain the PID:

`pidof x0vncserver`

Then kill it with the resulting PID from the above command.

`kill -15 PID` or `kill -SIGTERM PID`

You can also use `killall processname` where process name is the process you wish to kill provided you have the psmisc package installed. You can confirm that with the command `dpkg -l psmisc` which will provide output like this:

```
$ dpkg -l psmisc
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                        Version            Architecture       Description
+++-===========================-==================-==================-===========================================================
ii  psmisc                      22.21-2.1build1    amd64              utilities that use the proc file system
```

Sources:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tigervnc-users/lxRS20r2XFc

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/kill-process-in-linux-or-terminate-a-process-in-unix-or-linux-systems/

`man killall`

Comment: Thanks, would ```killall x0vncserver``` do the same job as above?

Comment: @SaTa updated answer