# How to create a new user defined command to kill processes using process name?

Tags: command-line, bash, kill, auto-completion, freebasic

Suppose I wanted to kill firefox , I just write pidof fi(press tab)refox (appears on its own) , then I write ' kill 'id given by pidof' ' on terminal.

I know that I can write 'kill `pidof firefox` ' but the autocomplete does not work .
So I wanted a command like mykill firefox (on which tab completion also work) which on the background runs 'kill `pidof firefox` '

mykill process name (with tab completion) -> kill `pidof process name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would to just use the pkill command instead. It can be found in the procps package. You use it like so:

```
pkill fir<tab>
pkill firefox
```

To get completion for nested commands, your shell (bash) needs to be smart and enable autocompletion in those scenarios. Unforunately, it looks like it does not. I believe the alternative shell, fish, does.

Comment: I agree on this but there is 1 difference that could matter: you kill all firefoxes and TS method kills 1. There could be 2+ running ;)

Comment: Thanx for your answer @Cameron , will surely use it but I want to learn how to implement auto complete in shell using bash so hoping that another answer answering that also appears :)
I would have also upvoted your answer if i had more than 15 reputation :P

Comment: Your shell allows you to create functions in your .bashrc which are available for use just like regular commands. I do not think bash supports autocomplete for functions, though. fish does not either.

Comment: There are `pkill` and `killall`. They can act in a similar way. To spot the differences between them you may give a look to [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/27543/196535) or to the other of the post.